# Adding files into a gulp stream during the pipeline

Tags: javascript, gulp, node-streams

I've got a gulp stream that reads a few hundred markdown files and runs through a series of pipes like so:

```
var mystream = src('app/pages/**/*.md')
    .pipe(frontMatter({
        property: 'fm',
        remove: true
    }))

    .pipe(data(function (file) {
        if (file.fm.title) file.fm.title_html = markdown.marked.parseInline(file.fm.title)
        if (file.fm.description) file.fm.description_html = markdown.marked(file.fm.description)
    }))

    .pipe(data(process_last_update))

....and like 10 more pipes writing the stream at the end....

    .pipe(dest('site'))
```

This all works. What I'm trying to do is during one of those pipe stages, I'm checking the markdown files frontmatter and if it has a certain value (array of strings), then I want to duplicate the file setting the path to what it finds in the frontmatter and add them to the stream.

This is the code I'm trying:

```
.pipe(data(function (file) {
        if (file.fm.slug_history) {
            file.fm.slug_history.forEach(slug => {
                let newfile = Object.assign({}, file);
                newfile.path = file.base + "/" + slug + "/index.html";
                mystream.write(newfile);
            })
        }
    }))
```

But the `.pipe(dest('site'))` at the end just isn't writing the additional files I've seemingly added to the stream. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include the entire pipeline?  (fill in the _"....and like 10 more pipes writing the stream at the end...."_ section)

Comment: unfortunately due to sensitivities I can't share everything.. i'm trying to share what's necessary to assess the issue.

Comment: OK I was able to get rid of that error, I'm going to edit the problem above now which is the dest('site') at the end just isn't writing the new files that I am *seemingly* adding to the stream....